# 500 - Internal server error. resource cannot be displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling

I have deployed my MVC application on IIS 8.0  server.
All static pages are working fine, but when I try to login it displayed this error.

Error Message

```
500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.


Module ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler 
Error Code 0x00000000
```

Below is the code from my web.config file

```
 <system.web>
    <trust level="Full"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <modules>
       <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

I have already set `customerror mode="Off"` and `httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"`

What can I do more to resolve this error?

Comment: every time I have run into the 500 error it has been an issue with my code.  The controller is hit but breaks on something in the controller

Comment: How can I view exact error

Comment: put a break point in your controller.  If the break point isn't hit then you have an issue on your view side.  make sure your developer console is open and you can look at details inside and hopefully find where your issue is